# libgdx - scene2d.ui label position

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

How can I dock a multiline `Label` to the bottom of the screen? There's the `Label.setY()` method but it works in some arcane way that makes no sense to me. I can get the approximate height of the label with `getWrappedBounds()` but I can't figure out how to use the label's height to set the position of the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot position directly a label, you would have to add to a class that is using WidgetGroup such as Table. Or you can a Container [that is supposed to be more lightweight than a Table] and add the label to it:

```
Label testLabel = new Label("testme",super.getSkin(),"gameName");
Container labelContainer = new Container(testLabel);
labelContainer.bottom();
```

Then the label should be displayed at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

You should prepare your label first and then place it:

```
skorTextLabel = new Label("Score " + level_skoru, skorTextStyle);
skorTextLabel.setPosition(
            ekran_genisligi * 0.5f - skorTextLabel.getWidth() * 0.5f,
            skorTextLabel.getHeight() * 0.3f);
```

"skorTextLabel.getHeight() * 0.3f" distance from bottom.